# Calculating the difference between current value in row and blank values per column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is like this (this is an example data frame):

```
id_row  Sample  wsts (xc)   wstm (xc)   wst1 (xc)
1   Na  2427.5  4542.5  2930
2   Na  1294.5  3642.5  1297
3   Ca  3048    5127.5  3456
4   Ca  2340    1729.5  2437
5   blank   2568.5  2529.5  2540
6   blank   2345    2001    2521
7   blank   2323    2121    2590
8   blank   2112.5  2129    2561
```

I'm trying to apply a specific normalization method to my data. This is the main idea.

First: calculate the average value of all the blanks in the same column, for example, rows 5 to 8 are blanks. So for the column `wsts (xc)` I need to calculate the average of those blank values on that particular column. Then do the same for the column `wstm (xc)` and for the `wst1 xc`. (in this case, I prefer not to specify all column names, because I have 100 in my real data frame).

Second, after the calculation of the blank average per column, I need to subtract the blank average value of that column from the values different from the blank, like `Na` or `Ca`. For example:

```
id_row | Sample | wsts (xc) |  wstm (xc) | wst1 (xc) |
1 |  Na | 2427.5-(average of blank in that column) | 4542.5-(...) | 2930-(...) |
2 |  Na | 1294.5-(average...) | ...
```

Third, when the new values are calculated, I would like to create a new column with the results and keep the old one (ideally) by the old columns. Here is an example (where: `old name (xc)_norm`, is the name of the normalized new column),

```
id_row | Sample | wsts (xc) | wsts (xc)_norm | wstm (xc) | wstm (xc)_norm | wst1 (xc) | wst1 (xc)_norm |
1 | Na | 2427.5 | new_value | 4542.5 | new_value | 2930 | new_value | ...
```

I think that to achieve this goal I need to create a function in R, so far I could not figure out how to do it without getting stuck.

Another option is to use Excel, which is more straightforward because I can set a function in one cell and apply it to the other rows, however, I do not want to do that.

Any idea how can achieve my goal?

Is there any function in R that allows me to achieve my goal?

Do I need to create a function?

Comment: In the result, do you still want the `blank` rows, or can they be dropped after their average is calculated?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, based on your question I would like to keep the average values of blank rows with their respective new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `across()` to specify the columns. It is very flexible in ways to pick exactly which column need to be transformed - here I have applied the function to all columns containing "xc" in their name, but you could list them, use another pattern, etc.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(across(
    contains("xc"),
    \(x) ifelse(
      Sample == "blank", 
      mean(x[Sample == "blank"]),
      x - mean(x[Sample == "blank"])
    ), 
    .names = "{.col}_norm"  
  ))
#   id_row Sample wsts (xc) wstm (xc) wst1 (xc) wsts (xc)_norm wstm (xc)_norm wst1 (xc)_norm
# 1      1     Na    2427.5    4542.5      2930          90.25       2347.375            377
# 2      2     Na    1294.5    3642.5      1297       -1042.75       1447.375          -1256
# 3      3     Ca    3048.0    5127.5      3456         710.75       2932.375            903
# 4      4     Ca    2340.0    1729.5      2437           2.75       -465.625           -116
# 5      5  blank    2568.5    2529.5      2540        2337.25       2195.125           2553
# 6      6  blank    2345.0    2001.0      2521        2337.25       2195.125           2553
# 7      7  blank    2323.0    2121.0      2590        2337.25       2195.125           2553
# 8      8  blank    2112.5    2129.0      2561        2337.25       2195.125           2553
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'id_row  Sample  "wsts (xc)"   "wstm (xc)"   "wst1 (xc)"
1   Na  2427.5  4542.5  2930
2   Na  1294.5  3642.5  1297
3   Ca  3048    5127.5  3456
4   Ca  2340    1729.5  2437
5   blank   2568.5  2529.5  2540
6   blank   2345    2001    2521
7   blank   2323    2121    2590
8   blank   2112.5  2129    2561', header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This approach looks closer to my main idea, maybe I'm wrong but how do you make sure that you are subtracting the blank average value of that column and not from other columns? I mean, how do you apply the calculation by column and not between columns?

Comment: That's what `across()` does, it applies a function to each column, one at a time.

Comment: Now I see, sorry for the confusion

Comment: For a simpler example, `df |> mutate(across(contains("xc"), mean, .names = "{.col}_mean"))` calculates the mean of each column, or `df |> mutate(across(contains("xc"), log, .names = "{.col}_log"))` calculates the log of each column.

Comment: Great, it is working! However, in one comment above I asked you how can I keep the average blank value in the new column. For example, the calculated average values from the first column must be in the new column (rows 5 to 8 in column one will be the average blank calculated from that particular column. Is it possible?

Comment: @Mauri1313 see updates